# Spark TF-IDF getting the words back from hash

Tags: java, hash, apache-spark, tf-idf

I am following [this example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html) from Spark documentation for calculating the TF-IDF for a bunch of documents. Spark uses the hashing trick for this calculations so at the end you get a Vector containing the hashed words and the corresponding weight but... How can I get back the words from the hash?

Do I really have to hash all the words and save them in a map for later iterate through it looking for the keywords? There is no more efficient way built-in Spark?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The transformation of String to hash in [HashingTF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/HashingTF.html) results in a positive integer between 0 and `numFeatures` (default 2^20) using [org.apache.spark.util.Utils.nonNegativeMod(int, int)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.html#nonNegativeMod(int,%20int)).

The original string is lost; there is no way to convert from the resulting integer to the input string.

Comment: _"The original string is lost; there is no way to convert from the resulting integer to the input string."_ Note that this is true for any good hash function: they're deliberately one-way.

Comment: Cryptographic hash functions are one-way hashes.  Standard hash functions are not interested in the one-way property. For example, the standard Java String hash is pretty easy to invert for (very) short strings. The goal is usually to minimize collisions in the output space.

Answer (score 5):

If you use CountVectorizer instead of HashingTF (TFIDF is basically a suit of the HashingTF transform and IDF fit), then it's probably better suited to your need because you can recuperate the indexed vocabulary.

```
String[] vocabulary= countVectorizerModel.vocabulary();
```

so that you know how to find them;

For instance, having a resulting  SparseVector like (11,**[0,1,3]**,[1.0,... , where [0,1,3] represents the indices of vocabulary terms encountered in respective text , then you can get the terms by referring to:

```
vocabulary[index]
```

If you need to to that in the context of LDA topic terms, the solution is the same.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a dictionary that maps all tokens in your data set into a hash value.  But, since you are using the hashing trick, there may be hash collisions and the mapping is not perfectly invertable.