# What is the difference between HashingTF and CountVectorizer in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Trying to do doc classification in Spark. I am not sure what the hashing does in HashingTF; does it sacrifice any accuracy? I doubt it, but I don't know. The spark doc says it uses the "hashing trick"... just another example of really bad/confusing naming used by engineers (I'm guilty as well). CountVectorizer also requires setting the vocabulary size, but it has another parameter, a threshold param that can be used to exclude words or tokens that appear below some threshold in the text corpus. I do not understand the difference between these two Transformers. What makes this important is the subsequent steps in the algorithm. For example, if I wanted to perform SVD on the resulting tfidf matrix, then vocabulary size will determine the size of the matrix for SVD, which impacts the running time of the code, and the model performance etc. I am having a difficulty in general finding any source about Spark Mllib beyond API documentation and really trivial examples with no depth.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A few important differences:

- partially **reversible** (`CountVectorizer`) **vs irreversible** (`HashingTF`) - since hashing is not reversible you cannot restore original input from a hash vector. From the other hand count vector with model (index) can be used to restore unordered input. As a consequence models created using hashed input can be much harder to interpret and monitor.
- **memory and computational overhead** - `HashingTF` requires only a single data scan and no additional memory beyond original input and vector. `CountVectorizer` requires additional scan over the data to build a model and additional memory to store vocabulary (index). In case of unigram language model it is usually not a problem but in case of higher n-grams it can be prohibitively expensive or not feasible.
- hashing **depends on** a size of the vector , hashing function and a document. Counting depends on a size of the vector, training corpus and a document.
- **a source of the information loss** - in case of `HashingTF` it is dimensionality reduction with possible collisions. `CountVectorizer` discards infrequent tokens. How it affects downstream models depends on a particular use case and data.

Answer (score 16):

As per the Spark 2.1.0 documentation,

> > Both HashingTF and CountVectorizer can be used to generate the term frequency vectors.

**HashingTF**

> HashingTF is a Transformer which takes sets of terms and converts
> those sets into fixed-length feature vectors. In text processing, a
> “set of terms” might be a bag of words. **HashingTF utilizes the hashing trick. A raw feature is mapped into an index (term) by applying a hash
> function. The hash function used here is MurmurHash 3. Then term
> frequencies are calculated based on the mapped indices. This approach
> avoids the need to compute a global term-to-index map, which can be
> expensive for a large corpus, but it suffers from potential hash
> collisions, where different raw features may become the same term
> after hashing.**
>
> To reduce the chance of collision, we can increase the
> target feature dimension, i.e. the number of buckets of the hash
> table. Since a simple modulo is used to transform the hash function to
> a column index, it is advisable to use a power of two as the feature
> dimension, otherwise the features will not be mapped evenly to the
> columns. The default feature dimension is 2^18=262,144. An
> optional binary toggle parameter controls term frequency counts. When
> set to true all nonzero frequency counts are set to 1. This is
> especially useful for discrete probabilistic models that model binary,
> rather than integer, counts.

**CountVectorizer**

> **CountVectorizer and CountVectorizerModel aim to help convert a
> collection of text documents to vectors of token counts. When an
> a-priori dictionary is not available, CountVectorizer can be used as
> an Estimator to extract the *vocabulary*, and generates a
> CountVectorizerModel. The model produces sparse representations for
> the documents *over the vocabulary*, which can then be passed to other
> algorithms like LDA**.
>
> During the fitting process, CountVectorizer will select the top
> vocabSize words ordered by term frequency across the corpus. An
> optional parameter minDF also affects the fitting process by
> specifying the minimum number (or fraction if < 1.0) of documents a
> term must appear in to be included in the vocabulary. Another optional
> binary toggle parameter controls the output vector. If set to true all
> nonzero counts are set to 1. This is especially useful for discrete
> probabilistic models that model binary, rather than integer, counts.

**Sample code**

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF, IDF, Tokenizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer

sentenceData = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0.0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
    (0.0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
    (1.0, "Logistic regression models are neat")],
 ["label", "sentence"])

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(sentenceData)

hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="Features", numFeatures=100)
hashingTF_model = hashingTF.transform(wordsData)
print "Out of hashingTF function"
hashingTF_model.select('words',col('Features').alias('Features(vocab_size,[index],[tf])')).show(truncate=False)
    

# fit a CountVectorizerModel from the corpus.
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="words", outputCol="Features", vocabSize=20)

cv_model = cv.fit(wordsData)

cv_result = model.transform(wordsData)
print "Out of CountVectorizer function"
cv_result.select('words',col('Features').alias('Features(vocab_size,[index],[tf])')).show(truncate=False)
print "Vocabulary from CountVectorizerModel is \n" + str(cv_model.vocabulary)
```

**Output is as below**

[image]

Hashing TF misses the vocabulary which is essential for techniques like LDA. For this one has to use CountVectorizer function.
Irrespective of the vocab size, CountVectorizer function estimates the term frequency without any approximation involved unlike in HashingTF.

Reference:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#countvectorizer

Comment: what do you mean Hashing TF "misses the vocabulary"? there may be collisions where different words/tokens are mapped to the same bin (feature), but it doesn't "miss". The number of collisions is minimized by controlling numFeatures param. C.V. is exact -not taking rare excluded tokens into account-. You can do a word count to get an idea what value for numFeatures is appropriate. I think depending on the situation, vocab size you can use either. I don't see any major difference. CountVectorizer does some work for you if you have an application where the vocab size keeps changing for example.

Comment: @Kai maybe he means, `CountVectorizer`, after fitting, returns a `CountVectorizerModel`, which has a [`vocabulary` member so you can see the vocab it extracted](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel) . `HashingTF` does not. Maybe this is why `HashingTF` is less "reversible" per the accepted answer "As a consequence models created using hashed input can be much harder to interpret and monitor."

Answer (score 6):

The hashing trick is actually the other name of feature hashing.

I'm citing Wikipedia's definition :

> In machine learning, feature hashing, also known as the hashing trick, by analogy to the kernel trick, is a fast and space-efficient way of vectorizing features, i.e. turning arbitrary features into indices in a vector or matrix. It works by applying a hash function to the features and using their hash values as indices directly, rather than looking the indices up in an associative array.

You can read more about it in [this paper](http://alex.smola.org/papers/2009/Weinbergeretal09.pdf).

So actually actually for space efficient features vectorizing.

Whereas `CountVectorizer` performs just a vocabulary extraction and it transforms into Vectors.

Comment: thanks. So hashing may produce the same index into the feature vector for two different features, correct? isn't that wrong though? e.g. if the hash computed the same index for say the feature Length and the Feature Width of some object.. did I get that right? in Text classification, then HashingTF may compute the same index for two very different words..

Comment: Yes, there can be collisions.

Comment: There can be collisions like every hash function. Nevertheless, the probability of that happening is very low considering the number of words that you might have.

Comment: @eliasah Actually not that low. With default settings (numFeatures 2^20) quite a lot depends on input and pre-processing.

Comment: @zero323 But the hashing function goes around 2 ^ 31 if I'm not mistaken. No ?

Comment: Yes, but `indexOf` is hash modulo `numFeatures` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31540959/1560062)

Comment: But we are still far from collision if we perform data cleansing (stem,lemm) @zero323

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102708/discussion-between-zero323-and-eliasah).

Answer (score 3):

The answers are great. Just adding a bit more context & code examples:

## Similarities/Importance of `CountVectorizer` and `HashingTF`

First, the [Spark website](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#tf-idf) describes ["TF-IDF"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)

> Term frequency-inverse document frequency (TF-IDF) is a feature vectorization method widely used in text mining

...and goes on to say...

> TF: **Both** `HashingTF` and `CountVectorizer` can be used to generate the term frequency vectors.

So that's why we should ask "what is the difference between CountVectorizer and HashingTF",or " when should we use one or the other?"

I tried to learn and demonstrate some difference between `CountVectorizer` and `HashingTF` in [this Google Colab](https://gist.github.com/theredpea/18c539249f12e979d75cdbf9b9db9458)

## API difference: `CountVectorizer` must be fit

- [`CountVectorizer` must be `fit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer), which produces a new
  [`CountVectorizerModel`, which can `transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel)
- vs [`HashingTF` does not need to be `fit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF), `HashingTF` instance can transform directly

For example

```
 CountVectorizer(inputCol="words", outputCol="features") \
      .fit(words_data_frame) \
      .transform(words_data_frame)
```

vs:

```
 HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="features") \
      .transform(words_data_frame)
```

In this API difference `CountVectorizer` has an extra `fit` API step. Maybe this is because `CountVectorizer` does extra work to create a vocabulary (see accepted answer):

> CountVectorizer requires additional scan over the data to build a model and additional memory to **store vocabulary (index).**

### Skip the `CountVectorizer.fit()` step

You **can skip the fitting step** if you can create a `CountVectorizerModel` **"with a-priori vocabulary"**, as [shown in example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#countvectorizer):

```
# alternatively, define CountVectorizerModel with a-priori vocabulary 
# spark website shows Scala syntax, here is Python syntax
cvm = CountVectorizerModel \
  .from_vocabulary(["a", "b", "c"], "words") \
  .setOutputCol("features")

cvm.transform(words_data_frame).show()
```

### `CountVectorizer` vocabulary means it is reversible

`CountVectorizer` builds a vocabulary, which is why you can *reverse* the process of transform [as mentioned in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35274038/1175496). In other words, when you use `CountVectorizer`, you can ["get the words back from the hash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831125/spark-tf-idf-getting-the-words-back-from-hash)

## Collision Difference: `HashingTF` Collision Potential

`HashingTF` may create **collisions**! This means two different features/words are treated as *the same term*. Accepted answer says this:

> ... a source of the information loss - in case of HashingTF it is **dimensionality reduction with *possible collisions***

Collisions are a problem **regardless of the value of `numFeatures`**, but are especially a problem the lower the value of `numFeatures`, like `pow(2,4)` or `pow(2,8)`). In this example:

```
words_data_frame = spark.createDataFrame([([
    'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 
    'six',  'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'],)], ['words'])
hashing = HashingTF() \
    .setInputCol("words") \
    .setOutputCol("features") \
    .setNumFeatures(pow(2,4))
hashed_df = hashing.transform(words_data_frame)
hashed_df[['features']].show(truncate=False)


+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|(16,[0,1,2,6,8,11,12,13],[1.0,1.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Let's analyze the "features" output; the output contains 16 "hash buckets" (because I used `.setNumFeatures(pow(2,4))`)

```
16...
```

While my input had 10 unique tokens, and `numFeatures` was large enough to fit all the unique tokens, *the output only creates 8 unique hashes* (due to hash collisions);

```
.... v-------8x--------v....
..., [0,1,2,6,8,11,12,13], ...
```

Hash collisions mean 3 distinct tokens are given the same hash, (even though all tokens are unique; and should only occur 1x)

```
...----------------v
..., [1.0,1.0,1.0,3.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0] ...
```

So if you need to avoid collisions:

- leave the default value of `numFeatures` (which [is 262,144<sup>1</sup>](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.HashingTF.html#pyspark.ml.feature.HashingTF.numFeatures)),
- or [**increase** your `numFeatures`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/mllib-feature-extraction.html)

> This [Hashing] approach avoids the need to compute a global term-to-index map, which can be expensive for a large corpus, but it suffers from potential hash collisions, where different raw features may become the same term after hashing. To reduce the chance of collision, **we can increase the target feature dimension, i.e., the number of buckets of the hash table.**

### CountVectorizer can have information loss too

`CountVectorizer` has `vocabSize` which is analogous to `HashingTF`'s `numFeatures`<sup>1</sup>

- That is, if `CountVectorizer.vocabSize` is too small (smaller than the count of unique tokens), certain words **won't be captured in your output/features**; this is **also a form of "information loss"** (see example below)! Compare to`HashingTF` with a too-small `numFeatures`, which would result in a collision.
- However, if your `CountVectorizer.vocabSize` is larger than the number of distinct terms, **all the distinct words will be represented in your output/features *without collision***. **That's** the significance of `HashingTF` "collision" potential; `HashingTF` collision is possible **even if you give a large `numFeatures` (larger than the count of unique tokens)**

This example shows how CountVectorizer can result in information loss if your `vocabSize` is too small. But that's different than a collision:

```
  cvm = CountVectorizer() \
      .setInputCol("words") \
      .setOutputCol("features") \
      .setVocabSize(8) \ # Notice the vocabSize is too small
      .fit(words_data_frame)
  count_df = cvm \
      .transform(words_data_frame)
  count_df[['features']].show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------------------------------------+
|features                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|(8,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice how the cvm.vocabulary does not include the word/token 'four', that's "information loss" -- because we gave too small a `vocabSize`:

```
cvm.vocabulary
['two', 'seven', 'eight', 'one', 'nine', 'six', 'three', 'five']
```

## Consistency across corpus (given the same `numFeatures` / `vocabSize`)

*Within* a corpus (a set of documents; i.e. a single dataframe), `HashingTF` and `CountVectorizer` will assign the same integer to a given token/word/term.

However, *across different corpus/dataframes*, **only `HashingTF` will assign the same integer** to a given token/word/term (Thanks @MutasimMim for this point; see the comments), and **only if you re-use a HashingTF; or the same value for `numFeatures` is used for each `HashingTF` you create**

For example, notice how CountVectorizer handles these two dataframes:

In the first dataframe, the token `'apple'` is assigned the integer `0`

```
+---------------------+-------------+
|words                |features     |
+---------------------+-------------+
|[apple, apple, apple]|(1,[0],[3.0])|
+---------------------+-------------+
```

In the second dataframe, the token `'banana'` is assigned the integer `0`, the token 'apple' is now assigned `1`, a different integer than the previous dataframe!

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------+
|words                          |features           |
+-------------------------------+-------------------+
|[apple, banana, banana, banana]|(2,[0,1],[3.0,1.0])|
+-------------------------------+-------------------+
```

In a `HashingTF`, the token `'apple'` is assigned the same integer (`13`) regardless of the dataframe. This consistency is one possible **benefit** of a hash function (specifically Austin Appleby's MurmurHash 3 function used by `HashingTF`):

```
+---------------------+---------------+
|words                |features       |
+---------------------+---------------+
|[apple, apple, apple]|(16,[13],[3.0])|
+---------------------+---------------+

+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|words                          |features             |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|[apple, banana, banana, banana]|(16,[8,13],[3.0,1.0])|
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
```

Note within **a single dataframe**, both CountVectorizer and HashingTF will be consistent in assigning an integer to a given token. The above example is just to illustrate *across dataframes* (which may never apply to you; merge your dataframes within a single problem?)

## Other Concerns

Consider that a [TF-IDF vectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) might be a better approach than a `CountVectorizer` or `HashingTF` alone. As it [says here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/text-classification/step-3):

> The problem with (count encoding) is that common words that occur in similar features... observed that tf-idf encoding is marginally better than (count encoding) in terms of accuracy (on average: 0.25-15% higher)...

`TfIdfVectorizer` is "equivalent to `CountVectorizer` followed by `TfidfTransformer`", so it **does not have hash collisions** like a `HashingTF`, and **does have** the API options of the `CountVectorizer` etc...

### Other API differences

- [`CountVectorizer` constructor (i.e. when initializing)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.html#pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer) supports extra params:

  - `minDF`: (min document frequency) minimum number of different documents a term must appear in to be included in the vocabulary
  - `maxDF`: (max document frequency) maximum number of different documents a term could appear in to be included in the vocabulary
  - `minTF`: (min term frequency) For each document, terms with frequency/count less than the given threshold are ignored
  - etc...
- [`CountVectorizerModel` has a `vocabulary` member](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel@vocabulary:Array%5BString%5D), so you can see the `vocabulary` generated (especially useful if you `fit` your `CountVectorizer`):

  - `countVectorizerModel.vocabulary`
  - `>>> [u'one', u'two', ...]`
- `CountVectorizer` is "reversible" as the main answer says! Use its `vocabulary` member, which is an array mapping the term index, to the term [(`sklearn`'s `CountVectorizer` does something similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52748588/1175496)

### Other Similarities

- <sup>1</sup>`HashingTF` [`numFeatures` default value](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.HashingTF.html#pyspark.ml.feature.HashingTF.numFeatures) is same as `CountVectorizer` [`vocabSize` default value](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.html#pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.vocabSize):

  - the default `numFeatures` for `HashingTF` is `pow(2,18) == 1 << 18 == 262144`
  - the default `vocabSize` for `CountVectorizer` is the same `pow(2,18) == 1 << 18 == 262144`

Comment: Answer is really helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Nate Anderson Sorry to dig up this old question, but do we know that if HashingTF is applied to two dataframes that share an entry in their respective "words" rows then the corresponding outputs will be the same?

Comment: Hi @MutasimMim , that's a great question so I upvoted it, but I don't know the answer. 

Do you mean that if one dataframe has "two too many" and another has "two to tango" whether HashingTF would assign the same hash to the shared word "two"? 

I **suspect** the answer is *no* but I'm not sure of the answer, and I'm not sure if I understand you -- if I do understand you, I feels like it's easy to test a few cases to find out definitively, I'll try to do it sometime...

Comment: @MutasimMim I was wrong, you were right (but you deleted your comment?) -- I should've known a **a hash function should generate the same identity for a given value**! . Therefore this is another important difference between `HashingTF` and `CountVectorizer`, isn't it? If you post it as an answer, I'll upvote your answer! For now I'll mention this difference in my answer in the meantime....

Comment: To try to answer @MutasminMim's question, I made [this Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/theredpea/2dccb3f05fe1011fcfefaf7b878f68be/exploring-hashingtf-vs-countvectorizer.ipynb#scrollTo=900kzQQPsJDs) . It shows multiple dataframes sharing the value "two". With `HashingTF`, the word "two" is **always assigned the hash 8**. With `CountVectorizer`, the word "two" is assigned the hash 0, **but not always**! `CountVectorizer` seems to assign a word's integer based on its frequency, then its location in the document? So not consistent across different dataframes.

Comment: @NateAnderson I haven't looked at the CountVectorizer, so I am just going to retype my deleted comment about HashingTF here. Assuming you are using the default Murmurhash3 hashing, all the instances of "two"s have the same byte representation and should therefore be hashed to the same integer (feature).

Comment: Thanks @MutasimMim , it's a really good point you made & proved.

Comment: Slight addition to my comment above: the comment holds assuming in both cases you are mapping to the same dimensional feature space. If the dimensions change, so does the behavior of the Murmurhash3, and the two "two"s might then get mapped to different features.

Comment: That's important, I guess that's what [the accepted answer means when it says "hashing depends on **a size of the vector**, hashing function and a document"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35274038/1175496)